# How to create a method for an already existing class so that it uses a variable, from which it is called as an argument?

Tags: java, class, generics, methods

Update: thank you, now I understand that it is impossible to do what is written below.

> Let's say I want to create an `add` method for `Integer` and I would
>   like it to work this way: `x.add(y)`, where `x` and `y` are
>   `Integers`. Is there a possibility to do this? The only thing I can
>   think of is to create a different class that extends Integer and add a
>   method for it, but is there any other way?

Just to be clear, the reason I was questioning it in the first place is that I need to create a generic class that should be able to do, for example, addition both for `Integer` and `BigInteger` and I don't want to make if cases that check what class is `T` to do that. So I thought it would be useful if it was possible to do the above. Now it is still unclear for me how to do that. Sorry for such a confusing question.

---

P.S. I'm new to Java and also not a native English speaker, so I understand that the question may be very silly or has already been answered, if that's the case, I'm sorry.

Comment: No, you can't add methods to classes in the JDK.  And because `Integer` is marked `final`, you can't extend it either.

Comment: You don't need to add this method. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html
But note that primitive wrappers as well as String are immutable.

Comment: you can't change the classes in the existing JDK library! You will have to write to your own class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

> Just to be clear, the reason I was questioning it in the first place is that I need to create a generic class that should be able to do, for example, addition both for Integer and BigInteger and I don't want to make if cases that check what class is T to do that.

Why not use `java.lang.Number` as generic type, `Integer` and `BigInteger` are both subclasses of `java.lang.Number`.

No, you cannot add a method to `Integer`, nor can you create a class that extends `Integer` because `Integer` is `final`, final classes cannot be inherited in Java.

If you just want to add two `Integer` objects, just use `+` because there is auto boxing and unboxing in Java, check this out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7.

You can create util class to provide static method to work around this:

```
class Integers {
    public static Integer add(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return i1 + i2;
    }
}
```

By the way, you can add extension methods in Kotlin, where you can do things like `1.plus(2)` to perform plus operations.

Answer (score 1):

I have an unclear question. If you want to create an add method inside an existing **Integer** class, you can not create it because it is final. Instead, you can create an add method within your own class.

```
public int add (Integer a, Integer b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: `C99` called. It wants its function back. ^^

Comment: @Turing85 Why did you mention C99? I do not understand C99 in Java

Comment: It was a joke. Since `C` has only structs, not classes, and structs have no member functions. The `C`-way of doing things is writing the functions and passing the struct in. In essence, it is what you did for `Integer`, but this leads to a decoupling of the object and its behaviour, which in return lowers readability.

Comment: @Turing85 Oh, I never thought of that. Sorry for the serious answers to the funny answers :)